# MySQL grouping giving 4 rows instead of 1

Tags: mysql, grouping

I'm having a hard time getting the rows to group like needed. It gives me 4 rows instead of 1. I'm sure it's something simple, but I can't figure it out.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  th.name Serial,
CASE WHEN td.parameter = 4854455 THEN TRIM(LEADING '0' FROM td.text) ELSE NULL END Auto_PF,
CASE WHEN td.parameter = 797902 THEN TRIM(LEADING '0' FROM td.text) ELSE NULL END Auto_IC,
CASE WHEN td.parameter = 797402 THEN TRIM(LEADING '0' FROM td.text) ELSE NULL END Auto_NIC,
CASE WHEN td.parameter = 4854430 THEN TRIM(LEADING '0' FROM td.text) ELSE NULL END Auto_E46
FROM thisdata td
INNER JOIN this th
    ON td.thisid = th.id
WHERE td.parameter IN ('4854455', '797902', '797402', '4854430', '6332168',
'6332160', '798102', '12000003', '12020956', '12020947', '12015253')
AND td.created >= (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
GROUP BY Serial, td.parameter, td.text
```

...
[Result1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Y5az.png)

Comment: GROUP BY only `th.name` should do the trick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should be aggregating only by the name, and then pivoting the `CASE` expressions:

```
SELECT
    th.name Serial,
    MAX(CASE WHEN td.parameter = 4854455 THEN TRIM(LEADING '0' FROM td.text) END) Auto_PF,
    MAX(CASE WHEN td.parameter = 797902  THEN TRIM(LEADING '0' FROM td.text) END) Auto_IC,
    MAX(CASE WHEN td.parameter = 797402  THEN TRIM(LEADING '0' FROM td.text) END) Auto_NIC,
    MAX(CASE WHEN td.parameter = 4854430 THEN TRIM(LEADING '0' FROM td.text) END) Auto_E46
FROM thisdata td
INNER JOIN this th
    ON td.thisid = th.id
WHERE
    td.parameter IN ('4854455', '797902', '797402', '4854430', '6332168', '6332160',
                     '798102', '12000003', '12020956', '12020947', '12015253') AND
    td.created >= (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
GROUP BY
    th.name;
```